# Gmail API for JAVA - Eclipse project - Read new mails and download attachments

Tags: java, eclipse, email, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I work on student project where I have to use **GMAIL API** (**Java**), to connect to mail server, get new messages and download attachments if there is any. I already done this with **JavaMail API**, but mail server that should use app doesn't accept **IMAP** and **POP3** protocols, it has own web service.

I have two problems.

1. I have troubles even with starting project in **eclipse**.
   First, I have no idea how to set up connection with mail server (for example gmail account) and how to provide username and password. I saw that gmail api for authorization uses **Oauth2**.
2. Second one is maybe easier to solve. When I have established connection to mail server, how to fetch unseen mails and download attachments?

I guess that second part I could do on my own, but without
    connection its even useless to try.
I was reading official documentation for few days and I am quite confused.

(Maybe if you have some code sample or similar example it would be nice)

**EDIT 1:**

Done that, now I have this error

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
```

**setAccessType** is not found in *com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder*

All Imports from [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) are there.

**EDIT 2:**

I am quite confused now

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /resources/credentials.json
```

Line:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/resources/credentials.json";
```

[File&Folder organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARiFr.jpg)

When I check `System.out.print(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

I get `F:\NBS\eclipse\FetchMail`

**EDIT 3:**

Deleted all files and started over again but eclipse still looks blind
[File not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcZ2.jpg)

**EDIT 4:**

Tested method `.getResourceAsStream(path)` inside Main method and it finds **credential.json** inside `\eclipse\FetchMail` or any other file i want

Then moved file to `\eclipse\FetchMail\resources` and call `.getResourceAsStream("/resources/credentials.json")` also finds file.

But when try this in `getCredentials` method from [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java), there is `FileNotFound exception`.

```
 private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/resources/credentials.json";


 private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)?. The authorization and authentication with the server is as easy as copypasting the code after doing the previous steps. It also does a mail list. You should open a new post for the attachment download task. I recommend you to try the Quickstart and comeback if you have specific issues with the code.

Comment: I tried but I am stuck on credentials.json. .
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/mbJyzZV/download.png">
How should I assign email address and password with this client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) to authorize and authenticate accounts in order to use the Google APIs. To do so, follow the next steps:

1. In your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), click on Credentials.
2. Click on **CREATE CREDENTIALS** and Select Oauth Client Id
   [image]
3. In this case, choose **Desktop App**
4. Set any **Name** and click on **Create**
5. You will get a screen with the **Client ID** and the **Client Secret**. These keys will authorize your account to use the APIs. They are stored in the credentials file. You don't need to do anything with them, so close the window.
6. Download the credential's JSON file.
   [image]

---

In the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) code, you will notice this line:

`private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";`

You have to set the path of your credentials file. Change the name of the file to yours.

When running the code for the first time, you will get a link to accept the permissions specified in the Scopes. This will generate an [Access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#4.-send-the-access-token-to-an-api.) which allows the application to access the API without asking for human interaction until it [expires](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.).

Comment: I done as you told, but have small problem.
I edited question for better formating.

Comment: Sorry, might made a mistake in step 3. Instead of Web Application, use Desktop App.

Comment: Eclipse can't locate credentials.json, I edited my post (EDIT 2)

Comment: Is the file you downloaded in step 6 named credentials.json? Is it located in `/resources`? Try to move it to the `eclipse\FetchMail` folder.

Comment: when I download it has name client_secret.......json (https://prnt.sc/scg4mo)(I changed it to `credentials.json`
It won't locate it in `eclipse\FetchMail` folder 
I changed code accordingly (`CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json"`)
won't even work with `CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json"`

Comment: Try to download the .json file from the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_1_turn_on_the) in the "Enable the Gmail API" button.

Comment: Now its downloaded credentials.json, but still eclipse wont locate it inside FetchMail folder. I tried even with absoluthe path and eclipse is unable to see it.
Project root is eclipse\FetchMail, and when I store credentials.json there, but relative path "/credentials.json" wont locate it.

Comment: Without the `/`, just "credentials.json" in `eclipse\FetchMail` doesn't work either?

Comment: I see. Put it inside the `resources` folder, since it's the default one. Leave the path as "credentials.json"

Comment: Its not default one (I made folder), but its not working again.
I put even credentials.json in each folder inside FetchMail folder and still eclipse acting blind. I will delete all files and start project over again.

Comment: I will try to reimplement methods  from quick start, you can see edit 4 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved, changed `.getResourceAsStream` with `FileInputStream(path)` constructor and it works.